# Blender model turning black when scaled down in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I made a model in Blender, which I would like to import into Unity.

When importing into Blender, at full scale, the colours show up correctly :

[image]

However, I need to scale it down (the original model is very large). And when I do so, all the colours turn black. All of a sudden, once passed a seemingly arbitrary threshold :

[image]

I tried UV unwrapping in Blender, as well as fixing normals (inside and outside). But it doesn't fix this problem.

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use 0.1(default) for **Scale Factor** on **Import Settings** of the Model.

[image: Scale Factor on Import Settings]

If it doesn't work, how about changing the shader into Standard/Color?
Maybe the issue comes from the shader can't handle the tiny scale because of floating-point precision.

Comment: Rescaling that way seems to work! Thanks a lot!