# Blenderexport FBX to Unity problems

Tags: unity-game-engine, mixer

I have problem. When I have my object in blender it looks like the first picture, but when I export it to Unity it looks different and like in the second picture. Can anyone help me?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmGPq.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32DZ0.png)

Comment: Already this kind of issue was fixed with this solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65222680/blender-model-turning-black-when-scaled-down-in-unity/65222832#65222832

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blender model turning black when scaled down in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65222680/blender-model-turning-black-when-scaled-down-in-unity)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the scale factor. If you have imported it to unity change the scale from m to cm

Comment: i can change m in blender to cm but this does not helps. Or you meant something different?